# Nuxt3 - nested page structure not working properly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I want to have nested routes in NUXT 3 so I created this file/folder strucutre (showing just the part where I strugle):

```
 - Pages
   - Admin
     - Index.vue
     - Users
       - Index.vue
       - OtherRoute.vue
```

This folder structure works well when I navigating via `<NuxtLink>` - I can access page like:

```
- domain.com/admin (Pages/Admin/index.vue)
- domain.com/admin/users (Pages/Admin/Users/index.vue)
- domain.com/admin/users/otherRoute (Pages/Admin/Users/otherRoute.vue)
```

The problem is that when I reaload the page, or access directly url domain.com/admin/users NUXT changes it to `domain.com/admin/admin-users`

For some reason NUXT cant resolve this url when accessing it directly, not via NuxtLink and throw 404 error. Is there a way to have page structury like this and solve the unexpected path changing?

**Edit 1**
[What happens Video](https://vimeo.com/817874508)

**Edit 2**

Users.vue Page

```
<template>
    <TitleH1>Users</TitleH1>
    <TileList :tiles='tiles'></TileList>
</template>

<script setup>
    definePageMeta({
        layout: "logged",
    });

    const tiles = [
        {title: 'Users', icon: 'ic:baseline-supervisor-account', to: '/admin/users'},
        {title: 'Roles', icon: 'material-symbols:lock-person', to: '/admin/roles'},
        {title: 'Units', icon: 'ph:tree-structure', to: '/admin/units'},
    ]
</script>
```

logged.vue (layout)

```
<template>
    <NavigationMain :key="$route.name" />
    <div class="flex">
        <NavigationSide />
        <div class="w-full">
            <div class="px-4 md:mx-auto xl:px-36">
                <Breadcrumb />
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
            <NotificationHub />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

auth.global.js (the only middleware which is runing on that page)

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    const { isLogged, proceedAutoLogin } = useAuthStore();
        if (!isLogged){
            if (to.name !== 'login'){
                if (await proceedAutoLogin()){
                    return navigateTo(to.name)
                }else{
                    abortNavigation()
                    return navigateTo('/login')
                } 
            }
        }else{
            if (!await proceedAutoLogin()){
                abortNavigation()
                return navigateTo('/login')
            }
        }
  })
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? Based on your codes. Accessing directly the `domain/admin/users` works just fine, except the `domain.com/admin/users/otherRoute`.  

Comment: Yeah I am sure, add link to video, even with DevTools open, refresh somehow mess the nested route, top level routes works great.

Comment: Strange. Have you double checked your codes? Based on the video, it looks like your are being redirected for some reasons? Perhaps double check on the `users` page and the `logged` layout or the `middleware`. I assume that there is a route guard on your app.

Comment: Hi, as I see it there is not much code, nothing what should create this weird behaviour - posted the codes above.

Comment: Mmmm, may I ask what are the codes inside `NavigationMain` component?  the `:key` value has the  `$route.name` which outputs the `admin-users`.

Comment: You were right man, the problem was in middleware. Posted answer bellow. I was actualy misslead by something in documentation and used wrong atribute to navigate.

Comment: Nice!! Happy coding ‍ 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on hints by @ReaganM the mistake was in middleware:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    const { isLogged, proceedAutoLogin } = useAuthStore();
        if (!isLogged){
            if (to.name !== 'login'){
                if (await proceedAutoLogin()){
                    return navigateTo(to.name)
                }else{
                    abortNavigation()
                    return navigateTo('/login')
                } 
            }
        }else{
            if (!await proceedAutoLogin()){
                abortNavigation()
                return navigateTo('/login')
            }
        }
  })
```

I was redirecting to `to.name`, the problem was that the name of nested routes is build up like `Folder-File` in my case `Admin-Users`. So I changed that part of code and redirecting to `to.path` and it works great.

Final middleware

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    const { isLogged, proceedAutoLogin } = useAuthStore();
        if (!isLogged){
            if (to.name !== 'login'){
                if (await proceedAutoLogin()){
                    console.log(to)
                    return navigateTo(to.path)
                }else{
                    abortNavigation()
                    return navigateTo('/login')
                } 
            }
        }else{
            if (!await proceedAutoLogin()){
                abortNavigation()
                return navigateTo('/login')
            }
        }
  })
```